# is there a way to capture network calls a site makes using python?

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I've looked and urllib(2), mechanize, and Beautiful Soup in hopes to find something that captures network calls such as pixel/beacon fires from a page. Unfortunately i'm not very familiar with any of them, and also not very clear on how to go about my search.

I'd like to use python to run through a series of web urls, and capture each ones networks call aka pixel fires. Would anyone know of a means or library i can start from inorder to accomplish this??

looked into webscrappying, but i don't want the html, instead i beleive i'm looking for the GET request the site makes.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you want, you want to log what requests a browser makes when displaying a page, in respect of many pages.

Your options are to script a browser using python (See: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming), or script the browser using javascript, and output your results in some way (I suggest JSON, over a request or to a file), and analyse them in python.

You'll probably find it easier to do the scripting in javascript, honestly.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility if you have access to the Firefox web browser is to install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), a powerful debugging tool that gives you the option to display all network traffic from a web page in the browser console. In order to transfer the output from the console to a file you will need to install the [ConsoleExport](https://getfirebug.com/releases/consoleexport/consoleExport-0.5b5.xpi) plugin for Firebug.

You will now be able to capture all the traffic from a web page to a file which you can then parse with Python.